# Selenium - How to click an image on the below scenario

Tags: selenium

There exist a table with grids and i want to select a grid by a name and remove its icd9 code alone. please note all grids have same icd9 code so i cant go with span id. below is the code. please let me know how to map the icd9 code span id="700>48283<-1$3" with div id="containerChloride"

```
<table class="x-grid3-row-table" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" style="width: 760px;">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td class="x-grid3-col x-grid3-cell x-grid3-td-testKey x-grid3-cell-first " tabindex="0" style="width: 98px; display: none;">
</td>
<td class="x-grid3-col x-grid3-cell x-grid3-td-testId " tabindex="0" style="width: 98px; display: none;">
</td>
<td class="x-grid3-col x-grid3-cell x-grid3-td-orderableYN " tabindex="0" style="width: 98px; display: none;">
</td>
<td class="x-grid3-col x-grid3-cell x-grid3-td-cmpAOETestIds " tabindex="0" style="width: 98px; display: none;">
</td>
<td class="x-grid3-col x-grid3-cell x-grid3-td-accessionTypeValue " tabindex="0" style="width: 98px; display: none;">
</td>
<td class="x-grid3-col x-grid3-cell x-grid3-td-collectedTime " tabindex="0" style="width: 98px; display: none;">
</td>
<td class="x-grid3-col x-grid3-cell x-grid3-td-testName " tabindex="0" style="width: 198px;">
<div class="x-grid3-cell-inner x-grid3-col-testName" unselectable="on">
<div id="containerChloride" onmouseout="hideImage('img42')" name="Chloride" onmouseover="showImage('img42')">
<span id="testHoverSpan" class="testWithImg" height="100%" width="100%" onmouseout="hideImage('img42')" style="position: relative; white-space: normal;">
Chloride
<img id="img42" onclick="removeTest("2A1");" onmouseout="hideImage('img42')" src="resources/images/button_delete.gif" style="visibility: hidden;">
</span>
<img height="15" width="16" alt="View" onclick="testDescription(1414);" style="cursor: pointer; padding-right: 5px;" src="resources/images/icon_view_handling_instructions.gif">
</div>
</div>
</td>
<td class="x-grid3-col x-grid3-cell x-grid3-td-7 x-grid3-dirty-cell" tabindex="0" style="width: 178px;">
<div class="x-grid3-cell-inner x-grid3-col-7" unselectable="on">
<span id="700>48283<-1$3Container">
<span id="700>48283<-1$3">
700&nbsp;
<a onclick="removeIcd9Code('700>48283<-1$3','2A1','48283')" href="#">
</a>
</span>
</span>
</div>
</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the xpath you can use to identify the link:
//*[@id="containerChloride"]//a

Comment: Hi sam, yes i have this already, but my doubt is if you see the code above, in the next td there is a span id. i need to click that using this container chloride as reference. how to do it? how to link 2 td using the @id="containerChloride" as reference

Comment: I was thinking you wanted the link.  If you want the span, then it's still easy: //*[@id="containerChloride"]//span[@id="700>48283<-1$3"]